# Can not merge multiple revisions in different issues at once for subversion

Tags: svn, merge

1. I have three issues to merge from one branch to another.
2. Each issue contains set of revisions.(Can not merge each issue individually
   since that leads to conflicts)
3. So I need to select revisions of one issue and again select revisions in other issue and commit them all once.
4. But when I select revisions from second issue previous
   revisions get cleared.

Comment: Why do you think conflicts will be avoided by doing the merge all together? And why can't you just resolve the conflicts while merging?

Answer (score 0):

Read `svn help merge` and discover: you *can* do it

```
svn merge -r A:B, C:D, E:F
```

but **MUST NOT DOING IT**: perform three merges with resolving conflicts in-between